# Explanations for attributes QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have one column in my attribute table with attributes "1", "2" or "3".

1 = normal route
2 = special route because of the event (every year)
3 = special route because of the event and construction site (or other) (only in one particular year)

It's all about the routes of public transportation during a marathon race.

Is it somehow possible to create an note/remark for these attributes? I'm leaving the company soon and others maybe wouldn't understand my logic..;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new column as text field and insert your description for each class (1,2, and 3). First you create the column, then you select all objects of the first class (1) (*select features using an expression*). In the field calculator you can write 'normal route' and click on *update selected*.

[image]

You can do the same steps for the other classes.

Comment: If you have different descriptions for different years you can use description columns for each year.

Comment: Thank you @ Hanne K. I hoped there is a description field similar to that for layer styles.

Comment: The description field is a new column (text field) named description. You can create several columns like descr_2012, descr_2015 and so on. In the attribute table (because of the dbf format) the column name must have no more than 10 characters.